# How do I move the parent div?

Tags: jquery

Let me preface that I know the images aren't showing up right (unless you've already loaded them), I just don't know why imgur doesn't want to play nice with JSFiddle.

I have several Divs (each with an individual ID) that contain a 3 option radio button. I want to move the whole div to the appropriate box. That is if the user clicks on the first option, the whole radio button moves to the High Interest DIV, if they click the 3rd it moves to #lowI, and the middle button should move it back. I was able to get it to work by creating an individual function for every single radio button, but I feel like it should be possible to make 3 functions, one for clicking Yes, Ok and No that moves the parent div to the appropriate location.

[Here's the latest fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aslum/r4crr/5/)

And here's my feeble jquery code:

```
$('.no').on("click", function (e) {
    $("label.no").parent().appendTo("#lowI");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on labels is flimsy. I would use the radio change event. It is much more semantically appropriate.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("input:radio").change(function () {
       var tmp = $(this).parent("div").detach();

       if($(this).val() == "yes"){
           tmp.appendTo('#highI');
       } else if($(this).val() == "ok"){
           tmp.appendTo('#nI');
       } else {
           tmp.appendTo('#lowI');
       }
    });
 });
```

Also see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZjWj/2/). The original fiddle didn't have jQuery enabled, so it was confusing for a bit. Don't forget to include it or nothing will work!

Comment: Perfect! And yeah... I probably actually had "working" code at one point or another, just didn't realize it because I didn't have jQuery turned on. However this is much more concise than any of my attempts, so I'm marking it as correct!

Answer (score 1):

Your radio button has the css property display as none. So JQuery won't handle the click on them.

You need to handle the click on the labels something like

```
$("label.no").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).parent().appendTo("#lowI");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

EDIT changed the selector asuming the label has the class no

Comment: so maybe if I move the `class="yes"` from the input to the label? My goal is to make 3 "functions" that move the divs around, not to have a function for every choice.

Comment: yes, moving the class to the label or better to the image. But if you move it to the image change the parent() function because the div won't be the direct parent.

Comment: But it will still register the `change` event on the radio `input`s, so use the `label` to trigger the `change`, and listen for that (rather than `click` events on the `label`).